# Apache FTPSClient fails to put file despite successful connection and login

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons, file-transfer, ftps

I am using Apache' FTPS Client to connect and place a file on an server over FTPS. But it fails on the [storeFile](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#storeFile(java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream)) method....

```
 String url = "myTestSTore.com";
 String user = "fake";
 String password = "reallyFake"

FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient();
ftpClient.connect(url);

ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode()

ftpClient.login(user, password);

def reply = ftpClient.getReplyCode();

println "Reply code after logging in is $reply"

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(randomFile)
def reply2 = ftpClient.getReplyCode();

println "Reply Code before attempting file upload is $reply2"

boolean storeFileResult = ftpClient.storeFile(randomFile.getName(), fis)
def reply3 = ftpClient.getReplyCode();

println "Store file  $storeFileResult, reply Code after file upload is $reply3"
```

The output from this is...

```
 06 Aug 2018 11:39:30 - Connecting to ftp server: myTestSTore.com
 Reply code after logging in is 234
 Reply Code before attempting file upload is 230
 Store file result is false , 
       and reply Code after file upload is 522
```

Based on the reply codes, it looks like we are able to connect and login. But the storeFile method returns false and the reply code after that is a 500.

Is there any way to tell why the file upload failed?

Simply returning false and giving a 500 gives no insight as to why the upload failed.

Comment: Can you call ftpClient.getReplyString() to get more information?